# want to send listview data to another activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

```
package com.example.selflistview;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        connect();
    }
    private void connect() {
      String data;
      List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,r);
      ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost/listview.php");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("STRING", data);
            try {

       JSONArray json=new JSONArray(data);
       for(int i=0;i<json.length(); i++)
       {
        JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);
        String name=obj.getString("name");
        String year=obj.getString("year");
        String age=obj.getString("age");
        Log.e("STRING", name);
        r.add(name);
        //r.add(year);
        //r.add(age);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //final String item = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "arg2 : "+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent view_det = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ViewDetail.class);
                view_det.putExtra("position",arg2);
                startActivity(view_det);

            }
        });
       }

      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

I want to send Year, name and age to another activity, i am able to get the positions at intent but not the other values. please help...

I am able to see those values in list., but not able to call at intent section.

Your help will be appreciated..

Comment: You can get this from your adapter. And don't use list.setAdapter(adapter); in each iteration. Set the adapter once and use notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: sir, can u please help me.., can u modify code for me please..? i am new to android

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView text;
List<String> r; //define list here
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        connect();


    }
    private void connect() {
      String data;
      r = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost/listview.php");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("STRING", data);
            try {

       JSONArray json=new JSONArray(data);
       for(int i=0;i<json.length(); i++)
       {
        JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);
        String name=obj.getString("name");
        String year=obj.getString("year");
        String age=obj.getString("age");
        Log.e("STRING", name);
        r.add(name);
        //r.add(year);
        //r.add(age);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,r);
        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //final String item = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "arg2 : "+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent view_det = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ViewDetail.class);
                view_det.putExtra("position",arg2);
        String name = r.get(arg2);//add this line to get name from the arraylist of that position
        JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(arg2); //you can get other two values from json object
            String year=obj.getString("year");
            String age=obj.getString("age");
        view_det.putExtra("name",name); //add this
        view_det.putExtra("year",year); //add this
        view_det.putExtra("age",age); //add this
                startActivity(view_det);

            }
        });
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: He also wants to get the name & year, maybe you could modify your code to get these from the JSON array?

Comment: Use the position to get the json object from json array and get the year and age as done in the final edit